# Convergent series with trigonometric functions like $a_{0}=m, a_{2n-1}=\sin(a_{2n-2}), a_{2n}=\cos(a_{2n-1})$

Tags: trigonometry, recurrence-relations, trigonometric-series

I have found by computation that
$$a_{0}=m, a_{2n-1}=f(a_{2n-2}), a_{2n}=g(a_{2n-1})$$
converges when $m$ - real and $f,g$ - some trigonometric function.
$$(f,g)\to(|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{2n-1}|, |\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}|)$$
So we have those pairs:
$$(\sin,\cos)\to(\approx0,694819, \approx0,768169)$$
$$(\sin,\tan)\to(\approx0,999906, \approx1,557086)$$
$$(\sin,\sec)\to(\approx0,976783, \approx1,786699)$$
$$(\sin,\csc)\to(\approx0,944039, \approx1,234669)$$
$$(\cos,\sec)\to(\approx0,446048, \approx1,108452)$$
$$(\tan,\csc)\to(\approx1,557701, \approx1,000086)$$
$$(\cot,\sec)\to(\approx0,477049, \approx1,125678)$$
And two special cases when they are the same:
$$(\cos)\to(\approx0,739085)$$
$$(\csc)\to(\approx1,114157)$$
Why those series converges (or have limit) to some results? What does they mean (relation with some constants)?

Comment: Why can we be sure of this convergence?

Comment: @saulspatz, I check it by computation. Only that reason. I can edit this part if you have some ideas.

Comment: I would "I have found by computation that ..."  When I read it, I thought you had some theoretical proof.

Comment: @saulspatz, thank you!

Comment: for cases like $(\sin,\cos)$ and $(\cos)$, it is easy to check $x \mapsto g(f(x))$ is a contraction mapping, so their convergence is not that surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%3Dsin(y),%20y%3Dcos(x)) on Wolfram Alpha.  Do you see how it explains your results?  Do you see why this must be so if the sequences converge?  This doesn't prove convergence, of course, but it tells you what the limits must be if the sequences converge.

Comment: Thank you twice! Looks like those results are useless.